# Unable to create reusable content type workflow in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have a requirement to create a reusable content type workflow in share point 2013. We are able to do the same in 2010 but we could not do the same in sharepoint 2013.

I followed the below link but after creating the workflow the content type automatically changed to All. The selected content type is disappear

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/33157.sharepoint-2013-create-reusable-workflow-on-content-type-using-sharepoint-designer-2013.aspx

I believe this issue is unanswered for such a log time.

Does anyone has solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Reusable workflows cannot be associated with content type if your site is running in 2013 UX mode.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/75286)

Comment: The answer to their question is that the thing they're trying to do cannot be done. It's like if someone asked me "how can I fly like a bird", the answer is "unless you're a bird, you can't".